# How duplicate a duplicated row in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How duplicate a duplicated row using jQuery?

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var thIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    var teste = "";
    var i = 0;
    var $tableBody = $('#tbl_id').find("tbody"),    
            $trSelected = $tableBody.find("tr:nth-child("+ thIndex +")"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trSelected.clone();
        console.log($trSelected);
        $trLast.after($trNew);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qgzx85o/

Comment: Your javascript provided here is very different from your jsfiddle.

Comment: sorry. i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$('body').on('click', 'tr', function()...`

The way you're doing it now, it only applies to existing rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qgzx85o/3/

Comment: I think you have to explain it to him.

Comment: I only made a minor modification of the jsfiddle he provided. I hope he'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with allowing the new rows to be clicked, then you should pass `true` to the `.clone` method.

[`.clone( [withDataAndEvents ])`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents)

> **withDataAndEvents (default: false)**
>   *Type: Boolean*
>   A Boolean indicating **whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements**. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.